# Oracle Apex - Date effective non-overlapping dates via validation and interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a validation on create and update of an interactive editable grid in Oracle Apex 5.1. I right click the `effective_start_date` column and then choose Create Validation. From here I then set Type to Rows Returned with the idea of doing a select where there are other rows for the same date range as the current row being created or updated.

To test I just entered `select 1 from dual` which I was thinking would then always error, but when I make changes I never get an error. Where am I going wrong and is this even possible in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the included help text:

> **Rows returned**
> Passes if the SQL query returns one or more rows.
> Fails if the SQL query returns no rows.
>
> **No Rows returned**
> Passes if the SQL query returns no rows.
> Fails if the SQL query returns one or more rows.

Use `select 1 from dual where 1=2` or switch to the other validation type.

Hope this answers your question so far.

Comment: Thanks! How do I refer to the interactive grid columns for the current changed or created row in my query? `:effective_start_date` does not seem to work although it does not error.

Comment: Is the Editable Region of the Validation set to the correct IG?

Comment: Yes, it defaults it automatically when you right click and create a validation on a column. I also checked and it is set correctly.

Comment: Turned out to be the `:id` that does not exist when creating, the other values work fine.